# Simplest way to update an input field using an AJAX call through jQuery from an SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm building an inventory system for the company I work for, and I have a problem that I was hoping could be solved with as little coding as possible. I want to make it so when someone clicks on an `option` from a `select` tag, an AJAX call using `$.ajax()` from jQuery would update

```
<input id="cratesRemaining">
```

Can I get the input field to update on selection of the option I guess would be the easiest way to ask.

Here's some of the code:

```
              <select id="busShell">
                        <option disabled selected="selected" class="default">
                            --- Choose Shell Index ---
                        </option>
              </select>
```

The select list will be generated using the `shell_index` column of each row in the SQL database.

Example of the resulting code:

```
    <option value="0">0488</option>
```

Would return the result "1.03" from the database column `crate_stock` when column `shell_index` is referenced.

Here is the jQuery script I have setup to call the php file:

```
                        <script>

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/php/busSubmit.php',

                                success: function(data) {
                                $('#cratesRemaining').val(data);
                                }
                            });

                        </script>
```

For some added information the database is named `paper_inventory` and the table is `bus_shells`. All shell indexes are 4-digit numbers, and it's only those two columns in that table. I have another table with 7 fields for paper selection, but I want to get the simple one working first.

Comment: Try triggering the ajax call by using something like `$('#busShell').on('change', nameOfFunctionWithAjaxCall);`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jeremy in comment.

```
$('#busShell').on('change', function(){ 
   $.ajax({
      url: '/php/busSubmit.php',
      dataType:'datatype you expect'
      success: function(data) {
      $('#cratesRemaining').val(data);
      })
});
```

Comment: Cool. the `.on('change', function(){});` Should do what I want it to do. I'll you know if it all works. It's going to take time to build the busSubmit.php so give me some time before I let you guys know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML just edit so the value in the option-tags is the same value as the value displayed. Like `<option value="0488">0488</option>`

JS/jQuery

```
$('#busShell').on('change', function() {
    $.post('foo.php', { shellIndex: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
        $('#cratesRemaining').val(data.crates);
    });
});
```

You now get `$_POST['shellIndex']` in your PHP script, so query your database with that and then return a json string with crates = remaining crates. Then it should be done! Look at `json_encode()` and don't forget to send the right headers `header('Content-type: application/json');`.

Answer (score 0):

There were some syntax errors in the code you provided. I fixed them though. as such:

```
 $("#busShell").on("change", function(){ 

 $.ajax({                                           
         url: "/php/busSubmit.php",
         dataType:"datatype you expect",
         success: function(data) {
              $("#cratesRemaining").val(data)}
         });
 });`
```